# Linking to Fidel API via Flutter http.dart package

Tags: api, flutter, http, curl, dart

probably a basic question, but I'm new to this:

I am trying to link to the Fidel test API environment. They give examples (https://reference.fidel.uk/reference#get-transaction) of how to do this via cURL. In this case the example is:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://api.fidel.uk/v1/transactions/84782884-6ab8-4885-820f-4cd081dd658f \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Fidel-Key: sk_test_50ea90b6-2a3b-4a56-814d-1bc592ba4d63'
```

If I run this in my terminal it works perfectly. But I can't get anything back if I try to run the same in my browser, or if I try to run it via the http.dart package in Flutter, which is where I need it to run eventually.

In Flutter I am writing it as:

```
void getData() async {
    Response response = await get(
        "https://api.fidel.uk/v1/transactions/84782884-6ab8-4885-820f-4cd081dd658f \'Content-Type: application/json' \'Fidel-Key: sk_test_50ea90b6-2a3b-4a56-814d-1bc592ba4d63'");
    print(response.body);
  }
```

I am sure it's a syntax thing that I don't understand. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It was just syntax! I solved by saying

```
Response response = await get(
        'https://api.fidel.uk/v1/transactions/84782884-6ab8-4885-820f-4cd081dd658f',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Fidel-Key': 'sk_test_50ea90b6-2a3b-4a56-814d-1bc592ba4d63',
        });
```

Will leave here in case anyone else, like me, gets stuck on the basics.